# Retrieve firestore reference

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to Android and Firestore, I was able to retrieve data from Firestore without any problems.
But, I'm not sure how to use the reference.

Here's the data structure for `person`;

```
{ name=abc, gender=male, title=software engineer, company=abc, useraccount=com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference@4878aac   
}
```

So I get the useraccount-reference like this;

```
DocumentReference userAccountRef = doc.getDocumentReference("useraccount");
```

My question is how to retrieve information from `user account` by using this userAccountRef? I don't see any API to get a document by reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a document from a `DocumentReference` you call `get()` on it. From the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document):

> ```
> userAccountRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
>     @Override
>     public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
>         if (task.isSuccessful()) {
>             DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
>             if (document != null && document.exists()) {
>                 Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot data: " + document.getData());
>             } else {
>                 Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
>             }
>         } else {
>             Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
>         }
>     }
> });
> ```

Comment: Great, it works, it happens that I forgot to DocumentSnapshot.